# How to replace part of a mapped network drive path using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2

At the company I work for we have recently changed file servers the old is called "EXAMPLE-FS-001" and a typical drive map would be \example-fs-001\staff_directory\staffname

The new server is called companyname.local and a typical drive map would be \companyname.local\shares\staff_directory\staffname.

We are using Server 2012 R2.

To help the IT Helpdesk from being bombarded with tickets about "My network drive doesn't work", I want to create a script that will run on the users computer and change the network drives path but just replacing \example-fs-001\ to \companyname.local\shares\ part.

The home drive has already changed, this will replace the manually set up mapped network drives.

I've been attempting to follow examples, but not many exist out there.

Example 1.

```
Set objNetwork = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")

Set colDrives = objNetwork.EnumNetworkDrives

For (i = 0 to colDrives.Count-1 Step 2){}
If  (colDrives.Item(i + 1) = "\\EXAMPLE-FS-001")
    {strDriveLetter = colDrives.Item(i)
     objNetwork.RemoveNetworkDrive strDriveLetter
     objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive strDriveLetter, "\\companyname.local\shares"}
End If
Next
```

Example 2.

```
On Error Resume Next
strOldServer = "EXAMPLE-FS-001"
strNewServer = "companyname.local\shares"
Set objNetwork = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set colDrives = objNetwork.EnumNetworkDrives
For i = 0 to colDrives.Count-1 Step 2
strThisServer = Left(Mid(colDrives.Item(i + 1), 3), InStr(Mid(colDrives.Item(i + 1), 3), "\") - 1)
If LCase(strThisServer) = LCase(strOldServer) Then
strDriveLetter = colDrives.Item(i)
strNewPath = "\\" $strNewServer "\" $Mid(colDrives.Item(i + 1), $Len("\\" & strOldServer       & "\") + 1)
If objFSO.FolderExists(strNewPath) = True Then
objNetwork.RemoveNetworkDrive strDriveLetter
objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive strDriveLetter, strNewPath
End If
End If
Next
```

I am new to PowerShell but see its fantastic use, I'd love to know if I'm on track with either of these codes.

Thanks,

Arkan

Answer (score 2):

I believe this will get you on track.  Keep the -whatif in there until you are sure the script will work for you.

```
 $OldServer = "\\EXAMPLE-FS-001\"
 $NewServer = "\\companyname.local\shares\"

 $drives = Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk | 
    ? {$_.ProviderName -like "$($OldServer)*" } | 
        % { 
            $Name = (($_.DeviceID) -replace ":", "")
            $NewRoot = (($_.ProviderName) -replace $OldServer, $NewServer)
            Get-PSDrive $Name | Remove-PSDrive -Force -whatif
            New-PSDrive $Name -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $NewRoot -WhatIf
        }
```